# Chinese characters on Windows 7 cmd

Tags: windows, utf-8, cmd

I have a little program in Java which needs to output (and also receive as input) Chinese characters. By default, these are shown garbled in Windows 7 command prompt.

I know I have to change the encoding using **chcp 65001** but:
 - When I simply type **chcp**, the console doesn't give anything back.
 - Same when typing **chcp 65001**, no response and the Chinese characters are still garbled.

I need to make Chinese characters availability depend only in cmd commands, as I want my program to be used in several computers (and so the user doesn't have to configure anything), so everything should be kept in a .bat file.

Any clue what's going on in my console?

Comment: The Windows command prompt simply isn't Unicode capable. You have to jump through hoops with it,and even then the result will not be what you are looking for. Why not just have your app display its own window instead?  Then you can handle the input/output however you want.

Comment: You would need to choose a font for the cmd window that contains the necessary Chinese characters. The fonts available by default (Consolas, Lucida Console, "Raster Fonts" are Latin-alphabet only).

Comment: @RemyLebeau That seems to be the only option. For that, however, I'm gonna need to get into GUIs, right? I've never used Java Swing or anything like that.